# How do you connect NIFI to IBM MessageHub through PublishKafka processor?

Tags: apache-kafka, ibm-cloud, apache-nifi, message-hub

I am trying to connect NIFI to IBM MessageHub but I am not getting any connection working.

Does anyone have a working example on how to configure it?

I get a timeout exception in the bulletinboard.

I have configured a **PublishKafka_0_11 1.4.0 processor**. 
Configured it as SASL_SSL, added standard ssl context service, added the jaas.conf

```
KafkaClient {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
  serviceName="Message Hub-bq"
  username="xxxxxx"
  password="xxxxxx";
};
```

And in the log I get:

*2017-11-24 13:47:01,407 INFO [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] o.a.k.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder Failed to create channel due to 
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to configure SaslClientAuthenticator*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the configuration you provided, it looks like you're missing the SASL mechanism. To connect to Message Hub this needs to be set to `PLAIN`.

From the NiFi docs about [PublishKafka](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-kafka-0-11-nar/1.4.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.kafka.pubsub.PublishKafka_0_11/index.html), it looks like you can directly provide Kafka setting using Dynamic Properties. You will need to set one of these to:

```
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
```

Also be sure you've specified the path to the JAAS file via `-Djava.security.auth.login.config=PATH` in your NiFi configuration.