# Configuring Apache NiFi for sending messages to Message Hub

Tags: ibm-cloud, apache-nifi, message-hub

What properties do I need to set to start sending messages from Apache NiFi `PublishKafka` processor to Message Hub in IBM Cloud?

[image]

I have entered these values for the reference

[image]

I am doing this on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you connect NIFI to IBM MessageHub through PublishKafka processor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47475010/how-do-you-connect-nifi-to-ibm-messagehub-through-publishkafka-processor)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the following Dynamic Property:

```
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
```

You also need to specify your credentials for SASL, use the username/password from your Message Hub instance:

- with PublishKafka_1_0, you also need to specify another Dynamic Property:

  ```
  sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required  username="USERNAME" password="PASSWORD";
  ```
- with PublishKafka_0_11, you need to create a JAAS file as described in the [SASL PLAIN section](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-kafka-0-11-nar/1.6.0) in NiFi's docs.  /org.apache.nifi.processors.kafka.pubsub.PublishKafka_0_11/additionalDetails.html

  You can also check [How do you connect NIFI to IBM MessageHub through PublishKafka processor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47475010/how-do-you-connect-nifi-to-ibm-messagehub-through-publishkafka-processor) for a JAAS file example.

Comment: thanx michael for your prompt reply....  where do i set this sasl.mechanism=PLAIN in nifi... im not able to find the place to put this

Comment: Click on the "+" icon in the top right hand corner on the "Configure Processor" window to add a custom property